# Sort an array from another array values in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I got an $actions array, and $actions_used array.

$actions_used looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  [2]=>
  string(1) "18"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "33"
}
```

$actions looks like this:

```
array(3) {
      [1]=>
      string(9) "Withdraw"
      [2]=>
      string(13) "Deposit"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "Blabla"
    }
```

I would like to sort $actions based on the value that is in $actions_used.

The correct output would be for $actions:

```
array(3) {
      [5]=>
      string(9) "Blabla"
      [2]=>
      string(13) "Deposit"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "Withdraw"
    }
```

Why? Because array key 5, "Blabla" has the biggest value "33" and then comes array key "2" which has value 18 and then at last comes array key 1, "Withdraw" which have 0 (no value)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$sorted_actions = array();
asort($actions_used);
foreach($actions_used AS $key => $amount) {
  $sorted_actions[] = array('amount' => $amount, 'action' => $actions[$key]);
  unset($actions[$key]);
}
$sorted_actions = $sorted_actions + $actions;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could sort the second array with `uksort` and actually compare the values from the first array in the custom comparer

e.g.:

```
uksort($arr2, function($i1, $i2) {
    return $arr1[$i1] - $arr1[$i2];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How would something like this work?

```
arsort($action_used);
foreach ($action_used as $k => $v) {
    $newArray[$k] = $actions[$k];
    unset($action_used[$k];
}
$newArray = array_merge($newArray, $action_used);
```

Comment: This works but what about the rest of the actions, that are not in the actions_used? They are not in the $newArray